# Another term for "real time decisioning"

Tags: predictive-models, real-time, explanatory-models

There is another term for "real time decisioning," (RTD) and I need it to locate a paper (by searching).  I've been beating my head over this all day.  I'm thinking it's "[something] moment", but that might not be right.

I expect this to get deleted as not being stats, please wait a day before doing that.

All of my Google searches are failing, such as "real time decisioning" "also known as."

RTD is real-time analytics that identifies an online sales opportunity, at the instant it's relevant. RTD is actually more general than that, while the term I'm trying to remember is this specific.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of **Online Inference**. Usually behind these analytics are predictive models. And nowadays these models are built using machine learning.

I think it helps to separate the `training` of the model (where it learns from historical data) and `inference` (when you ask the model to give you a prediction).

Both **training** and **inference** can be either offline or **online**. (I prefer the term **Batch** instead of offline)

Even if the term you're looking for is `online`, there's still a difference between whether you care about training or inference.

The most common scenario is **Batch Training, Online Inference**. That means someone took a lot of historical data and built a predictive model using machine learning. No matter what fancy terms you use to describe it, that model is basically just a function. It takes inputs and spits out a result (aka a decision). In order to actually use that function, a computer is sitting somewhere waiting for it to be sent a row of data, so it can respond what the decision is. So when you log into an app, or visit a website, it is asking the server to calculate the decision in real-time. That's online.

There is also **Online Training** which is much more complicated and less often used in the real world. This is when a model is already built and working exactly as I described above, except as time goes on it takes new data and relearns some of the model. It might help to think of it like Batch-Training just repeating itself many times per day.

**Batch Training, Batch Inference** - most common method

**Batch Training, Online Inference** - useful for apps, websites, code running in devices

**Online Training, Online Inference** - the holy grail

**Online Training, Batch Inference** - I don't think this would ever happen

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I finally found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it.

"Digital business moment" or "transient opportunity"

Hiltbrand, T. (2015). Fire up your social media strategy with big data analytics. Business Intelligence Journal, 20(3), 8-16